# Javafx 8 Font converts text to upper case A's

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, javafx-8

I have a problem using custom Fonts in Javafx 8.
Whenever I try to display a text it gets convertet to upper case A's

[image: Outpout when executing the code]

my code goes as follows:

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application {
    private Canvas can;
    private GraphicsContext gc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400);

        stage.setTitle("Test");

        can = new Canvas(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
        gc = can.getGraphicsContext2D();

        root.getChildren().add(can);

        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();



        InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("Font/SSF4ABUKET.ttf");
        Font font = Font.loadFont(is, 30);
        gc.setFont(font);
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillText("This is a test", 10, 200);
    }
}
```

If I try this Font in a normal Text Editor (e.g. Open Office) it works perfectly fine.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you at some point have the text as "AAAA"? The only explanation I can think of is that your IDE is running an older version of your code...

Comment: Hi @sillyfly I never used another text and I double checked that the newest version of the code is executed. I also found out that it must be a problem within the font because other fonts work without any problems. But it still confuses me that it has no problems in Open Office.

Comment: It's interesting that your text and image have the same number of characters, as if all codes mapped to the same glyph; it's odd that the font is acceptable to Open Office but not to `Font.loadFont()`.